# How to force-merge a git branch into another?

Tags: git

We have two branches, `master` (stable/live) and `stage` (testing). When deploying, `stage` is merged into `master` and `master` will be deployed.

Back in time someone (and this is certainly not a synonym for myself) did several commits (hotfixes) on `master` only.

Now when merging `stage` into `master`, the files affected from those hotfixes won't be merged anymore, they will just ignore changes in `stage` branch.

This seems to be the way git works - which btw alienates me. I considered `cherrypick`ing the master commits or `rebase`ing but, due to lack of knowledge, don't know if any of this will succeed - or how to do it properly.

What is the best way to merge these off-sync files so that changes from both branches will survive?

**UPDATE**
Merging did happen as expected; I just got too confused about the resulting diff until I eventually realized it's only a one-way-merge.

Comment: I don't see how creating these hotfixes on master could be an issue. Merging `stage` into `master` on the next release should work fine - the hotfixes are kept, and the new commits are applied on top of them.

Comment: What you *should* do, however, is merge `master` to `stage` to bring those hotfixes back to test-land.

Comment: Would have thought so, too, but new commits aren't applied to these files on merge ... Merging `master` back into `stage` seems like an obvious and good advice and I'll give it a try, ty!

Comment: No prob, I'll put it as an answer :) Hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see how creating these hotfixes on `master` could be an issue. Merging `stage` into `master` on the next release should work fine - the hotfixes are kept, and the new commits are applied on top of them.

What you *should* do, however, is merge `master` to `stage` to bring those hotfixes back to test-land.
Your two branches will be in sync and everything should be ok again.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend rebasing:

```
git rebase --onto master <hash of the commit before making changes on stage> stage
```

You can obtain the hash with `git log`. You need the last commit on the `stage` branch before you started making changes.

If you have modified the same file on both branches git will ask you to resolve conflicts. You can do this using `git mergetool` or manually, then proceed with `git rebase --continue`.

This will add hotfixes to the `stage` branch and then you will be able to merge it  with `master`.